# Travelling to India from US via Germany; do I need a transit visa?

Tags: visas, transit

I have a valid US visa as I study there. I am returning back home via Germany. Do I need a transit visa in Germany?

Also, the ticket has no information about the flight terminals.

Comment: Is it in one booking, and what German Airport are you flying through?

Answer (score 2):

If you are just in transit and do not intend to go out of the airport, you wouldn't need a visa.

However, to visit Germany you would need a Schengen visa.
Ref: https://www.schengenvisainfo.com/visa-application-indian-passport-holders/

Comment: @Ravi when in transit, you do not need to know the terminal you are in, since you won't be leaving it, just waiting.